# Extract Data using sed, awk or grep

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

How can I extract the content in the below script tags using shell command like grep, sed or awk?

```
    <script>
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "API Dev :: UP";
        document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "API QA :: UP";
        document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "API Regression :: UP";
        document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = "API Pre-Prod :: UP";
    </script>
```

-Thanks

Comment: What specific information would you like to extract? Could you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: Are u trying to extract the content between script tags

Comment: Is your goal to get just that set of strings? The reason I ask is based on how specific you want to be. Any script on the page would be picked up if your goal were to get anything within a script block. If you are screen scraping, you will most likely have to contend with other authors' scripts being extracted as well for one example.

Comment: Use an HTML parser, not a regex-based text processing tool.

Comment: I have a basic html page which only one script tag. So I am looking to extract all the lines with the script tag. From the above example, I was expecting this output:

Comment: `document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "API Dev :: UP";
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "API QA :: UP";
document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "API Regression :: UP";
document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = "API Pre-Prod :: UP";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description:
`sed '/script/d' sample.csv`

uses `/script/` to match lines contains string `script` and `d` is to delete those lines.

Alternatively, use `grep "document.getElementById" sample.csv`. Use grep to match the pattern(s)
Output:

```
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "API Dev :: UP";
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "API QA :: UP";
    document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "API Regression :: UP";
    document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = "API Pre-Prod :: UP";
```

Comment: `grep "document.getElementById" sample.csv` works for my scenario since I have few other tags like html, head and body in my actual html file.

Comment: @sunil `sed -n '/document.getElementById/p' sample.csv` will work :)

Answer (score 0):

some other alternatives

```
$ grep -Ev '</?script>' file
```

or

```
$ gawk -v RS='</?script>' '!(NR%2)' file
```